# How to Listen For BLE signals in background using Flutter and Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to figure out how to add a listener in flutter that would listen for BLE signals even in the phone background, while the app is off. Is it possible to achieve this using flutter_blue?